# How to select from where field like abc****ef****?

Tags: regex, regex-group, kdb

I have a table with the following fields:

```
t:([]id:til 5; field:("abc_xy_ef";"abc_ef";"abc_de";"abc_xy_uv";"abc_ef_ghi"))

id field       
---------------
0  "abc_xy_ef" 
1  "abc_ef"    
2  "abc_de"    
3  "abc_xy_uv" 
4  "abc_ef_ghi"
```

I would like to select only the rows where field follows the pattern `"abc_[anything]_ef[anything]"` such that the resulting table would be:

```
id field       
---------------
0  "abc_xy_ef" 
1  "abc_ef"    
4  "abc_ef_ghi"
```

Comment: Is your [anything] going to be a fixed number of characters?

Comment: No, it can be any length, with characters in [a-z], [A-Z] or [0-9].

Comment: `"abc_[anything]_ef[anything]"` won't match `"abc_ef"` as you have 2 underscores in the pattern, you may need to tweak your example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limitations of regex in kdb can be overcome by placing multiple where clauses to filter to the desired result

```
q)select from t where field like "abc*", field like "*ef*"
id field
---------------
0  "abc_xy_ef"
1  "abc_ef"
4  "abc_ef_ghi"
```

Obviously this isn't the most efficient method as after each clause, all the results are processed again. You can pull in a more comprehensive regex library  such as pcre2 or re2 as specified in the documentation https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/regex/#regex-libraries

Answer (score 3):

Callum gave the correct answer - a double filter is the best approach.

For the purpose of curiosity, it is possible to create a "state machine" to handle more advanced regex but it would be horribly inefficient on the large scale

```
q)m:({0};{2*x="a"};{3*x="b"};{4*x="c"};{5*x="_"};{5+x="e"};{7*x="f"};{7})
q)match:{7=1 m/x}
q)match["abc_xy_ef"]
1b
q)select from t where match each field
id field
---------------
0  "abc_xy_ef"
1  "abc_ef"
4  "abc_ef_ghi"
```

Details here: https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/regex/#regex-in-q

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, KDB currently does not support this regex matching.

If you have multiple patterns or could break your pattern into multiple patterns then you can also match them in a single condition.

For example, as mentioned in other answers you can split your pattern into two- "*abc*" and "*ef*". And then match on all patterns and select the rows which match with all the patterns.

```
q)  select from t where all field like/: ("*abc*";"*ef*")
```

You can add more patterns to the list.

Performance would vary depending upon data pattern. If there are more matches for the first pattern then this solution would run faster than multiple conditions in where clause and vice versa.

Below example creates a table by duplicating records in your example table to increase the matches on the first pattern. This solution runs fast as there are multiple matches for the first pattern.

```
q) t:1000000#([]id:til 5; field:("abc_xy_ef";"abc_ef";"abc_de";"abc_xy_uv";"abc_ef_ghi"))
q) \ts select from t where all field like/: ("*abc*";"*ef*") ; / 46 25166144
q) \ts select from t where field like "abc*", field like "*ef*"; / 53 25166144
```

Similarly, for below table matches on the first pattern is 0 so multiple filter solution runs fast.

```
q) t:([]id:til 1000000;field:1_1000000 {"_" sv 2?'3#enlist 1_.Q.a}\"")
q) \ts select from t where all field like/: ("*abc*";"*ef*") ; / 43 3146000
q) \ts select from t where field like "abc*", field like "*ef*"; / 9 1048816
```

So basically this solution would take more or less same time for a same table size with different data patterns.